# Archiving a directory using PHP Zip Archive

Tags: php, archive

I'm trying to archive to a .docx file using the php ZipArchive class. The structure of the archive should be:

- docProps
- _rels
- word
- [Content_Types].xml

(the first three are directories)

The problem is that the _rels directory isn't archived.

Tried changing permission -> didn't work.

EDIT: Tried renaming the file and then uploading it -> didn't work.

EDIT2: getStatusString() returns No errors;

Both addEmptyDir() and close() return true;

- PHP: 5.4.9
- OS: ubuntu

Comment: Have you looked at any code that actually does this already, such as [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)? Perhaps it might give you a few clues where you're going wrong!

Comment: Hello - yes I have, but that isn't the issue. I don't need any advanced features for generation of word files. I just need to add the directory to the archive.